# Redirecting a page based on the referer URL via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, redirect

How can I, by using JavaScript, redirect a page based on `document.referrer`?

```
http://www.url.com/thisfolder/someotherfolder    <-- referer

http://www.newurl.com/thisfolder                 <-- new url
```

This is what I have tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
   if (document.referrer == '' ||
       document.referrer.indexOf('www.website.com/thisfolder/andanything-here') != 1) {
       top.location="http://www.newpage.com";
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
var ref=document.referrer;
if (ref.indexOf('www.oldurl.com')>0){
  ref=ref.replace('http://www.oldurl.com/oldfolder/');
  window.location.href='http://www.newurl.com/'+ref;
} 
</script>
```

The above code gets the referrer. It checks whether the old site is in use. If so, it strips the beginning and redirects to the new site. The code should be self-explanatory.

The code works if your old site has urls like:
www.oldurl.com/subdirectory/page1.htm

And the new site has the same set of files but a different path, e.g.:
www.newurl.com/page1.htm

Comment: i need it to redirect everything that comes after the last "/" also (is this possible?)

<script>

if (document.referrer=='http://www.url.com/thisfolder/*/andanything-here-also')
 window.location.href='http://www.newurl.com/thisfolder';

</script>

Comment: An explanation is always necessary with code examples

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
 location.href = "http://www.newpage.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = 'http://www.url.com/thisfolder/someotherfolder';
a.hostname = 'www.newurl.com';
a.pathname = a.pathname.replace(/\/[^\/]+$/g, '');
location.href = a.href;
```

Comment: @Seth It just modify the hostname and pathname of the original URL and set it to `location.href` to redirect. Since I don't know what conversion did OP need actually, so the regex replace is just an example.

Comment: This is what you would want to add to the answer so that SO maintains quality answers.